# How can I create a new frame that does not inherit the splits from an existing frame?

Tags: frames, window-splitting

From time to time I like to pop open a new frame (GUI window) with `cmd + n` which gives me a new frame. However if I create a new frame and I have an existing frame with 2 splits the new frame also is open with the same 2 splits with the same buffers. I'd like this new frame to open with a single split by default, is this possible?

Comment: I have no idea what command you use to pop open a frame, but is `C-x 5 2` what you're looking for?

Comment: The question is not very clear. By "2 splits" do you mean 3 windows in the frame, and by "single split" you mean 2 windows?

Comment: as @T.Verron notes `C-x 5 2` (`make-frame-command`), opens a new frame with no window splits out of the box.

Comment: C-x 5 2 (make-frame-command) is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the comments the Dan and T. Verron answered my question and shared C-x 5 2 with me which is exactly what I was looking for.